# Mplab x Debugger view data in pointers

Tags: debugging, microchip, mplab

I have an MPLAB x V4.05 project using a PIC18F26K22 and has messages defined :

```
    const char * UITopLevelText[LANGUAGES][4] = {
    {
       //12345678901234567890
        "CALIBRATE HCT-201", //  use current text
        "RECEIVE TEST FILE",
        "PERFORM TEST",
        "SEND TEST RESULTS",
    },
    {
       //12345678901234567890
        "CALIBRATE HCT-201", //  use current text
        "RECEIVE TEST FILE",
        "PERFORM TEST",
        "SEND TEST RESULTS",
    }
}
```

I am trying to view the text data in the debugger and I can not find a way to display the text data. I must be missing something. Or is there a way to display data at a memory location?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

(1) If you hover over UITopLevelText, you will see the address of the start of the 2x4 array of pointers to the strings (assuming `LANGUAGES` equals 2). You just have to follow the pointers. You will have a problem in that the pointers will be referencing const data which is stored in ROM instead of RAM. If your device has paged access to ROM via RAM addresses, then you will only be able to "see" the strings when TBLPAG is set properly (to put your data into view). This is if you are using "Window|PIC Memory Views|File registers".

(2) Therefore, you may have to use the "Window|PIC Memory Views|FProgram memory" debug view in MPLABX, which can be set to view information as hex rather than code.

(3) Set your build options so that a map file is produced when you build. You can then see where your constant data is stored.